# Difference between batch_size in TimeSeriesGenerator and model.fit batch_size

Tags: python, time-series, regression, rnn, recurrent-neural-network

im wondering if there is a difference between the batch_size set in the TimeSeriesGenerator and the batch_size in the model_fit. I create some RNN Forecasts for timeseries.

```
train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(data=scaled_train, 
                                targets=scaled_train, 
                                length=n_input, 
                                batch_size=batch_size, 
                                stride=1,
                                sampling_rate=1,
                                shuffle=False,
                                start_index=0, end_index=None)
```

The in model.fit

```
hist = model.fit(train_generator, # also take batch_size, shuffle, etc? 
          steps_per_epoch=1,
          epochs=1000,
          #batch_size=32,?
          #shuffle=False,? 
          verbose=1, 
          validation_data = valid_generator,
          validation_steps=len(valid_generator), 
          callbacks=[early_stop]
         )
```

I did create the TimeSeriesGenerator for valdidation and for trainingdata.
Do I need to specify the batch_size again in the model.fit. If I do will it influence my results? Maybe multiplicate the batch_sizes??
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the keras docs for the `fit` method [here](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method) it is said

> Do not specify the batch_size if your data is in the form of datasets, generators, or keras.utils.Sequence instances (since they generate batches).